# Asking the wrong questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, question-quality

Lately, it seems like a lot of questions are the wrong questions - I hate to single one out, but [this one](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1937847/how-to-modify-key-in-a-dictionary-in-c), for example.  The questions aren't bad, but they are simply things you don't do, or shouldn't do, or need to do because people have gone too far down a bad design or a misconception or whatever.  And of course, the user doesn't give motivation for the situation usually.

My concern is that there are tons of answers which are "don't design your database that way" after someone has already got a performance problem with a million rows of data in some screwy schema **AND** the format of Stack Overflow is not really conducive to collaborative analysis of large problems.

Any discussion going on here about being able to branch answers into a full blown wiki discussion of design issues? - i.e. a fully editable single page discussion of a design.

Answer (score 15):

Chances are that someone else will want to do the same misguided thing. They will find these questions and see answers that guide them to a better solution. This is a good thing. Bring on the wrong questions, so we can give them the right answers!

Comment: I'd wanted to post an answer to this question, but when I read this I realized I couldn't have said it better myself. +1

Comment: The ones with fundamentally bad setups are also the ones who aren't that resourceful, and there are some in the community who will downvote you for not actually answering the question.

Comment: My point was that I don't think the current structure of answers lends itself as well as it could to a full analysis of the design options which should be "rolled back" to eliminate the need to solve the problem presented.

Comment: People can always link to their own wiki or blog, but then other people cannot fully participate there and it fragments things.

Answer (score 3):

A humiliating example to support [Jon B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/27414/jon-b)'s answer:

As a perpetrator of at least one [demonstrably wrong question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8) and despite an overwhelming desire to purge said question from living memory, I can see very clearly the value here.

Answer (score 0):

For users with low reputation, there is a popup that appears when answering, which specifically *discourages* you from asking for clarification of the question:

> [image: popup on the StackExchange answer form]

I interpret that as saying *don't criticise the question*. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this. It appears only for users with low reputation (not sure about exact numbers), and is rather new. When this discussion was posted, such thing didn't exist. I clarified the answer a bit.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for taking the time to explain.